# Extension cord female end-3 plug end

Tags: electrical, extension-cord

I was needing to replace female end on extension cord. The existing female end is made to accept 3 plugs on that end. Do replacement ends like that exist or will it have to be converted to just a single plug on the female end.

Comment: You’ll have to replace it with a single. They have short cords like 3’ that you can then plug in.  If you have a garden variety 16gauge cord, it may be cheaper to replace the entire cord.  For a quality female cord cap and a 3foot adapter your going to spend more than a new garden variety cord.  This however changes quickly the heavier duty and longer the original cord was.  Shop both the parts you need and the new cords and compare.

Comment: It is a 25 ft, 15 amp, 12 ga cord.

Comment: For the level of effort involved, simply replacing the cord seems like an easier option to me.

Answer (score 3):

It would be called a "replacement triple tap" and you might try asking an electrical supply shop if they have any.  Seems like they used to be made, but not anymore for compliance reasons.

Otherwise, a "triple tap adapter" is the solution Tyson is suggesting.

Comment: Triple taps are dollar store items, and work on any extension cord.